# Coverting integer to float. Issue solved but wondering why

Tags: ios

As show in the image below:
[image: like this]

I was comparing the value of textfield with 99999999, and would behave different according to the result.

Finally i found integerValue or doubleValue method returns the correct value,
but who can explain me why? why floatValue is 100000000 here? is't predictable？

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Single precision float only has around 6 decimal digits of precision - int and double have more. Learn more about floating point here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter`

Comment: @PaulR yeah,i have learned about the precisions of different data types,thanks. Still wandering why is 100000000 ：）

Comment: @CoderWang: most likely it just happens to be the nearest representable value given the finite precision of a float.

Comment: @PaulR i've had a basic understanding,no longer torn.tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions.

Most decimal fractions can not be represented exactly as binary fractions. A consequence is that, normally, the decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

There are docs you can refer to:http://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/Floating_point_arithmetic